# The type or namespace name 'MvcJsonOptions' could not be found in .net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core-3.1

I have converted my .net core 2.2 to .net core 3.1. I am getting issue with following below.

Getting complain about `MvcJsonOptions` inside `IOptions<MvcJsonOptions>` options.

Also getting issue with `MvcOptions` inside `IOptions<MvcOptions>`.

Another one is, `options.SerializerSettings` inside `SetupSerialiserSettings(options.SerializerSettings)`.

```
        public JsonDeserialiser(IOptions<MvcJsonOptions> options) : this(options.Value.SerializerSettings)
        {

        }

           services.AddSingleton<IObjectModelValidator>(
            s =>
            {
                var options = s.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcOptions>>().Value;
                
            });
           services.AddControllers()
                .AddJsonOptions(options => SetupSerialiserSettings(options.SerializerSettings))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,you can refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcjsonoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and find `MvcJsonOptions` only applies to `2.1, 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 2.2`.And you can also refer to [Breaking changes to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App in 3.0](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/325).

In .net core 3.1,the internal usage of Json.NET in ASP.NET Core has be replaced by the new platform-provided JSON APIs.Refer to [The future of JSON in .NET Core 3.0](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/90).

So you can try to add package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`,and use like the following code(from the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-3.1#add-newtonsoftjson-based-json-format-support)):

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    ...
});
```

Comment: Hi @Yiyi You, could you please provide solution for `JsonDeserialiser(IOptions<MvcJsonOptions> options)`? Thanks